# Convert list of strings with scientific notation to decimal numbers

Tags: c#, list, decimal, scientific-notation

I have a list of strings (numbers with scientific notation) and I want to convert it to real numbers; my idea was convert it using a loop:

```
    for (var i = 0; i < time.Count; i++)
    {
        timeD.Add(decimal.Parse(time[i], System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Any));
    }
```

but the values of the outcoming numbers are wrong. The values of my list are:

```
7.6923076920E-10
1.5384615380E-09
3.2051282050E-09
4.8717948720E-09
```

and the output is

```
7,6923076920
15,384615380
32,051282050
48,717948720
```

Any ideas why this is happening and how do I fix it?

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice that. Specifying the CultureInfo worked, Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that you have a CurrentCulture where the '.' is not the decimal separator. So 7.6923076920E-10 is the same as 76923076920E-10. Try specifying CultureInfo.InvariantCulture on parsing:

```
 decimal.Parse(time[i], System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care about Globalization you can declare you own NumberFormatInfo

```
var nfi = new NumberFormatInfo();
```

So if your input decimal separator is "." or "," you can set it in

```
nfi.NumberDecimalSeparator
```

Then you can use

```
var num = decimal.Parse(time[i], nfi);
```

CultureInfo.InvariantCulture always assumes that the decimal separator is "."